# How to temporarily disable iPad support

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-app

I have built a universal iOS-app. The iPhone part is ready to go, the iPad part still needs more work and should not be shipped.

How can I build a version of this project resulting in a binary that only contains the iPhone version?

Simply removing "Main storyboard file base name (iPad)" in info.plist does not seem enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Target's 'summary' page (click Project in left panel, select Target, then choose Summary tab), set the Devices pulldown to iPhone. Previously it would have been 'Universal'. The binary will still contain the iPad data, but iPad users won't be able to install it and it'll be marked as iPhone-only on the App Store.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In **Target -> Summary** you can select **Device -> iPhone**

In **Build Setting -> Target Device Family** select iPhone only

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In **info.plist** file **delete** the row named `Main storyboard file base name`.

Also change the `Target Device Family` to `iPhone`

Comment: had to get rid of `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` key and values